# Intersection of cubic and a plane in $\mathbb P^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $P \subset \mathbb P^3$ be a plane.Then we know that the intersection of an  irreducible cubic surface $X$ with the plane forms one of the following in the plane :

$(1)$ a non degenerate cubic curve or

$(2)$ the union of a nondegenerate conic curve and a line or

$(3)$ three distinct lines.

So does there exist similar kind of result(s) for reducible cubics in $\mathbb P^3$ ?

Can someone give me any reference.

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: The defining polynomial of a reducible cubic factors as a product of a linear and quadratic term or a product of three linear terms. Can you conclude from here what must happen when taking the intersection with a plane?

Answer (score 1):

Wlog your plane is (the closure of) $\Bbb{A}^2= \{ [x_0:x_1:0:1]\in \Bbb{P}^2\}$. Your cubic surface is  $X=Z( f(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3))$ where $f(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)\in k[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]$ is an homogeneous polynomial of degree $3$.

Then $$X\cap \Bbb{A}^2 = Z(x_2, f(x_0,x_1,x_2,1))\cong Z(f(x_0,x_1,0,1))\subset \Bbb{A}^2$$
$f(x_0,x_1,0,1)\in k[x_0,x_1]$  is a polynomial of degree $d\le 3$.

If it is non-zero, since $k[x_0,x_1]$ is an UFD we have $$f(x_0,x_1,0,1)=\prod_j f_j(x_0,x_1)^{e_j}$$ where each $(f_j(x_0,x_1))$ is a prime ideal and $\sum_j e_j \deg(f_j)=\deg(d)$.

That doesn't leave many choices.